# SQL code in variable within a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have been googling for hours and have yet to find an answer to the error I keep receiving. I have the following code:

```
$varFirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
$varPast = $varFirstName.' Past';
$varPresent = $varFirstName.' Present';
$varPastandPresent = $varFirstName.' Past and Present';
$CharacterID = "SELECT CharacterID FROM CHARINFO WHERE FirstName='$varFirstName'";

$sql="INSERT INTO CHARACTER_RELATIONS (RelationshipWith, CharacterID)
VALUES('$varPast', '$CharacterID'),
('$varPresent', '$CharacterID'),
('$varPastandPresent', '$CharacterID')";

mysqli_query($con,$sql)
or  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
```

And I keep getting "Error:" every time I run this. If I make $CharacterID=49; then it works just fine, so I feel like something is wrong with "SELECT CharacterID FROM CHARINFO WHERE FirstName='$varFirstName'" but I can't figure out what. Suggestions?

Comment: Suggestions? Such as parameter binding, or using a subquery, or a prior database query, and getting rid of mixed-cased variable names?

Comment: get the real error `mysqli_error($con)` that `mysql_error()` doesn't mix with mysqli_

Comment: and your POST array(s) might be failing. check for errors on PHP. you're also not querying on the first query.

Answer (score 2):

$CharacterID= "SELECT CharacterID FROM CHARINFO WHERE firstName='$varFirstName'"; // this returns an array object. so you have to retrieve value of each row by using mysqli_fetch_array() as given below
    //print_r($CharacterID);exit();// to check the array value and also you dint executed the $CharacterID. ie mysqli_query($con,$CharacterID);

```
$varFirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
$varPast = $varFirstName.' Past';
$varPresent = $varFirstName.' Present';
$varPastandPresent = $varFirstName.' Past and Present';
$Character= "SELECT CharacterID FROM CHARINFO WHERE FirstName='$varFirstName'";// this returns an array object
       $CharacterID= mysqli_query($con,$Character);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($CharacterID)){
        $id=$row['CharacterID '];
        $sql="INSERT INTO CHARACTER_RELATIONS (RelationshipWith, CharacterID)
        VALUES('$varPast', '$id')";      
        mysqli_query($con,$sql)
        or  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));  
}
```

Comment: how can you run a query inside `mysqli_fetch_array()`? that would translate to `while($row=mysqli_fetch_array(SELECT CharacterID FROM CHARINFO WHERE FirstName='John'))`

Comment: if this is some SQL guru trick I don't know about, I'd sure like to know about it.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add mysqli_query ()

Comment: you should edit your answer for the OP and for future visitors who may not know what to do here. edit: thanks for the edit ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- second time you helped me to find the code error.thanks :).